# Order second table before joining

Tags: hibernate, join, criteria

I have `TopicEntity` which contains many `PostEntity`. Each `PostEntity` belongs to exactly one `TopicEntity`. I need to sort topics by the last post creation date, that is the `creationDate` property of the newest post in the topic.

What I think needs to happen:

1. Get the topics
2. Join with posts that belong to topic
3. Sort the posts by their creation date
4. Get the newest post from each topic and use its date to sort the topics

This is what I have currently:

```
this.session.createCriteria(TopicEntity.class, "topic")
    .createAlias("topic.posts", "post", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    .addOrder(Order.asc("post.creationDate")).list();
```

This does NOT sort the topics in any way. I believe it is because it does not perform points 3 and 4 from the list.

Anyway, could you hint me the proper way of achieving the desired result? I would prefer Criteria, but if HQL is required, that's fine.

Comment: If you want the last posts first, you need Order.desc(), and not Order.asc().

Comment: I tried both, they do not seem to work / order correctly. Do you suggest that the above code SHOULD be working?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I indeed think that should work. Show us example data, the generated SQL query, and example output.

Comment: The query breaks when there are more than 1 posts in a topic. This is because the query orders only by the FIRST post in a topic, not the last one. So if I could reverse the order of the PostEntity table before joining, then the topics would be sorted by the newest posts... If that makes any sense...